# py2exe with different parts of apps

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, py2exe

Let's say I have 5 different python files:
`main.py, first.py, second.py, third.py, last.py`

Each of the files, after `main.py`, does something different through a button on `main.py`'s screen. I know how to use py2exe:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['main.py'])
```

Now, how would I compile all of these into EXE files such that I could still use the buttons to open the other .py files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I didn't realize is, I imported the other files into the `main.py` file, and they became modules! When you use py2exe, it compiles the modules. These can then be used in the program, for example:

`main.py`

```
from first '''Python File Name''' import *
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox

root = Tk()
def helloCallBack():
      tkMessageBox.showinfo(hi_function('Joe'))

B = Button(root, text ="Click Me", command = helloCallBack)

B.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

`first.py`

```
def hi_function(name):
   return 'Hello %s'%(name)
```

Python takes `first.py` and imports it as a module. Py2exe takes the modules in `main.py` and converts them to PYD files. So, the main thing is, you don't need to modify the code to call the .exe file. Simply, just import the other .py files as modules and py2exe will do the rest.

I'm going to put this on the community wiki for others to learn from.

Answer (score 1):

You could compile each file seperately into EXE file and then modify your code in main.py to call the EXE files instead of the functions in your .py files.

Comment: The only problem is that the main screen now freezes after you call the `first.py` when before it wouldn't have a problem running.

Comment: Is there a way you could refresh your screen trough your main.py code?
Maybe you could redraw your main screen after using your compiled first.py. I need more information on your main.py code to give you a more precised answer.